# Contour of combined objects in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I am a newbie in design and Inkscape and I think this question is very simple.

I have two objects (for example , circles) that overlap partially. I need to draw a contour of the entire object (the set of two circles). I've tried group (ctrl+G) or combine (ctrl+K) options but none of them do what I want. Here is a image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3oHn.jpg

Comment: Hi David, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not certain that I correctly understood what you want, but *Path → Union* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>) should do the job. You may need to apply *Object to Path* in advance.